# How to speed up row-wise computations on a data.frame using alternative functions to apply family?

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, statistics, apply

I have a data frame with 10,000 rows and 40 columns. I am trying to apply a function to each of these rows. For each row, I am expecting to return a scalar which is the value of the statistic I am calculating in this function. Below is what I have done so far;

```
library(dfadjust)
library(MASS)

# Creating example data #

nrows=10000
ncols=40
n1=20
n2=20
df=data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# Function to evaluate on each row of df #

get_est= function(x){
mod = rlm(x~cov$group)
fit = dfadjustSE(mod)
coef = fit$coefficients[2,1]
se = fit$coefficients[2,4]
stats = coef/se
return(stats)
}

# Applying above function to full data #

t1=Sys.time()
estimates=apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))
t2=Sys.time()-t1

# Time taken by apply function

Time difference of 37.10623 secs
```

Is there a way to significantly decrease the time taken to implement get_est() on the full data? The main reason I need to speed up the computation on a single df is because I have 1000 more data frames with the same dimension and I have to apply this function to each row to each of these data frames simultaneously. To illustrate, below is the broader situation I am dealing with;

```
# Creating example data

set.seed(1234)
nrows = 10000
ncols = 40
n1 = 20
n2 = 20
df.list = list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  df.list[[i]] = data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
}

# Applying get_est() to each row and to each of data frame in df.list #

pcks = c('MASS','dfadjust')
all.est = foreach(j = 1:length(df.list), .combine = cbind, .packages = pcks) %dopar% {
  cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))
  est = apply(df.list[[j]], 1, function(x) get_est(x))
  return(est)
}
```

Even after parallelizing it is taking hours to finish. My ultimate objective is to significantly cut down the time to obtain "all.est" which will contain 10000 rows and 1000 columns where each column has the stats estimates for the respective data set. Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a `data.table` could be an alternative and/or parallel computing.

Comment: @user2554330 I tried using a matrix object also but it did not bring down much time when using apply. Did you get evidence that my MWE is faster using matrices? If so, can you please post that answer.

Comment: @MartinGal So far I have also experimented with parallel computing (in my MWE) , data.table and dplyr's rowwise function but found not much improvement. If you have found any improvement using data.table can you please post that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some preprocessing of data we can adjust the `rlm` function so there's less overhead:

```
x3 <- as.matrix(cbind(1L, y))
colnames(x3) <- c('(Intercept)', 'x')
w = rep(1, nrow(x3))

get_est= function(x){
  mod = rlm(x3, x, weights = w, w = w)
  fit = dfadjustSE(mod)
  coef = fit$coefficients[2,1]
  se = fit$coefficients[2,4]
  stats = coef/se
  return(stats)
}
```

I got 12 seconds instead of 18 seconds for initial approach. ~33% improvement

For larger speedups I would suggest looking into `rlm` and `dfadjustSE` functions and try to optimize those for your specific needs (removing unnecessary checks etc., as you are calling those functions millions of times). But that probably will be quite time consuming and better performance is not guaranteed. Maybe there are other packages with similar but faster functions?